# Matlab gfrank() function returning the wrong rank

Tags: matlab, matrix

The function gfrank(A,p) in matlab is supposed to return the rank of a matrix A in GF(p) where p is prime.

But it seems that there is something wrong with this function. as it returns impossible values for some matrices.

For example for the 10*9 matrix:

```
 0     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0
 1     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1
 0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     1
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     1
```

in GF(29), the function returns 10, which is impossible as it is larger than one of the dimensions.

The example is found using this code:

```
M = 10;
pP = [];
Y =[];
for P = 19:100
    if isprime(P)
        P
        pause(3)
        for i = 1:100
            A=round(rand(M,M-1));
            pP = [pP,P];
            if(gfrank(A,P) > M-1)       % A IS AN (M-1)*M MATRIX.
                disp(A);                % IF RANK OF A IS GREATER THAN OR 
                disp(gfrank(A,P));      % EQUAL TO M, WE HAVE AN ERROR!
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Any updates around this?